# Ionic Serve Command gives "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: ionic2

When I write `ionic serve` or `ionic generate page test` I get a syntax error I'm not really sure why that's happening though. Here's the full error...

`home:nabil-app txt-19$ ionic generate page test
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Heres my github link https://github.com/sealio-io/sealio-app

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No, if i remeber correctly I just created a new ionic application.